# gdb stops at breakpoint, but no code is shown

Tags: c++, gdb

I've recently changed compilers from the Oracle Studio compiler on RHEL7 to Clang on RHEL8 due to no support of the oracle compiler.  I'm trying to debug our application using GDB, but running into some issues I am yet to find a solution for.

I can set a breakpoing with:
b class::function or
b file.cc:linenumber

It does break when it hits that breakpoint, but no code is shown at that location.  Funnily enough, some stuff does, and in this case, it shows line numbers in the base class.

this is the stack on break:

```
Thread 41 "dms" hit Breakpoint 2, 0x0000000000880f44 in
User_Registrar::login(Address const*, int, char const*, Boolean,
RWCString) ()
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000000000880f44 in User_Registrar::login(Address const*, int,
char const*, Boolean, RWCString) ()
#1  0x0000000000878dfb in
User_Registrar::userLoginRequest(UserLoginRequest*) ()
#2  0x0000000000871597 in User_Registrar::processMessage(Message*) ()
#3  0x00000000009cd530 in MessageHandlerObject::processMessageQueue
(this=0x7fffe8068010) at BaseObjects.cc:488
#4  0x00000000009cd40e in
MessageHandlerObject::processMessageQueueStartup
(thisInstance=0x7fffe8068010) at BaseObjects.cc:447
#5  0x00007ffff69d887c in stl_thread_start_rtn () from
/opt1/dms/lib/libthread.so
#6  0x00007ffff643318a in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007fffee095dd3 in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) up
#1  0x0000000000878dfb in
User_Registrar::userLoginRequest(UserLoginRequest*) ()
(gdb) down
#0  0x0000000000880f44 in User_Registrar::login(Address const*, int,
char const*, Boolean, RWCString) ()
(gdb)
```

Am I missing something like a limit or something similar?

Things I have checked:
Yes, it is being compiled with -g
objdump does show the debug_info for the source file
gdb does show it has loaded the source file

Comment: Try `gdb --tui`

Comment: I see the window for source, but when it breaks it just says No source available.  I can "up" the stack to no 4 for example and it shows code in BaseObjects, but not User_Registrar.

Comment: If source exists gdb will show an `at` after function name in a stack trace, but I found there's no `at` after `User_Registrar`. Where is your `User_Registrar` defined?

Comment: --tui doesn't work in Msys2 or Msys, if that's your environment you need to just use the list command.

Comment: Also, you can't step into code you don't have, start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so 's code isn't accessible to your debugger.

Comment: I'm not trying to step into code in start_thread().  I'm trying to step into the top level which is in User_Registrar which IS our code.  I've created the breakpoint with b User_Regisrar.cc:5161 and it is breaking in the function that line corresponds to, but no source is "available" despite it being in the ELF debug_info.

Answer (score 2):

> `(gdb) where`
> `#0  0x0000000000880f44 in User_Registrar::login(Address const*, int, char const*, Boolean, RWCString) ()`

Note that *there is no file / line info* for this level -- *that* is the reason GDB doesn't show source.

Why did this happen? Clang omits file/line info under certain conditions when optimization is in effect (as far as I understand, when code is inlined and re-ordered, it is sometimes hard to keep code to file/line association).

If you can disable optimizations, or add `__attribute__((noinline))` to the `login()` function, you'll have a better debugging experience.

If you must debug this particular function with optimizations, you'll have to disassemble it and reconstruct the code to file/line association "by hand".

Comment: Could you please give me a link/docs for "by hand" method ? , I interested in it. Thanks

Comment: @long.kl The "by hand" method amounts to: decompile the function into C-like code and fuzzy match that code to the source you have. The resources you'll want to search for are "reverse engineering", "decompilation", etc.

Comment: All of this code is compiled with the "-g" flag so has debug symbols etc.  Even with the __attribute__((noinline)) the effect is the same.  Seems to be happening quite a lot across the board, usually to do with threads.  Don't suppose you know of any other clang compiler options perhaps..

Comment: @BradMitchell "All of this is compiled with `-g`" -- yes, but _is it_ compiled with or without _optimization_ ? Also, which version is "Clang for RHEL8"? I suspect it's pretty ancient, in which case you may have better luck with more recent Clang.

Comment: clang-12.  Compiled with -g -O0 pretty much like every article I've read on stackoverflow which goes anywhere near GDB and clang compiled code.  I just find it strange it works for some code compiled the same way vs others.  V. frustrating.  If i can't find a solution I'll look for a newer clang and see how I go with that perhaps.

Comment: @BradMitchell Well, with `-g -O0` what I described above is entirely unexpected. There is probably some other explanation, but without http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it's hard to guess what it might be.

Answer (score -1):

If gdb doesn't know where to look for the source file, you can use the `directory` command to add a path: [gdb directory command](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gdb/html_node/gdb_48.html)

Comment: This _isn't_ the problem here.